# Symfony PdoSessionHandler with an external application

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, session, pdo

I'm using Symfony for my Administration Platform and as a way to securly authenticate my users.

After athentication, I grant them access to an application I built without Symfony (can't rebuild it with Symfony).
I use Symfony PdoSessionHandler to save the user athentication in the Database and I need to read it with my non Symfony application to give them access and to know which user it is.

In the Symfony environement I have no problem to set and get variables in the sessions, but when I'm outside Symfony I can't find how to access the data. I want perform a simple check like this:

```
if($_SESSION['authenticated'] == 'true'){...}
```

and get the user id with a `$_SESSION['UserID']`

Before Symfony, I used this to manage my sessions : https://github.com/dominicklee/PHP-MySQL-Sessions

Thanks for helping !

Comment: The most simple solution is instantiate PdoSessionHandler in your legacy application and set as session handler (PdoSessionHandler implements \SessionHandlerInterface) with session_set_save_handler PHP funcion before session_start.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I'm really a beginner with these PHP configurations. My Symfony and my Legacy application are in two separate subdomaines. Should I create a new page in my legacy subdomain using https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php ?

I'm still a bit confused about how to instantiate PDOSessionHandler in the legacy application.

Comment: well ... the constructor has good documentation ... https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php#L173 Try to `session_set_save_handler(new \..\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler($yourPdo)); session_start();`

Comment: Thanks, I just managed to make it working :)

Comment: Using my solution? If yes, I will publish the Answer.